# How can I browse Cydia repos without an iOS device?

Tags: ios, applications, jailbreak, cydia

My understanding is that [Cydia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cydia) is a mechanism for accessing third-party software repos on iOS. (The equivalent of [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)) for macOS.)

However, I am having trouble locating the "default" Cydia repos, and browsing them to see what software is available. How can I do this without an iOS device?

For example, is there an equivalent of the https://f-droid.org (a similar tool + website for Android)?

Comment: relevant link: https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Cydia.app

Comment: This has gotten a couple close votes, and I’m not sure why each individual repository should share the same organization / structure / search ability as any others. For example, isn’t this like asking if all social media has similar privacy or export capabilities. the obvious answer is - not necessarily - different tools have different implementations. Maybe I’m missing something that makes this clearer to answer.

Comment: @bmike All Cydia repos are apt repos(Cydia is a front-end for apt) and therefore share the same basic structure.

Comment: I thank @Abc for correcting my assumption and adding an excellent answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cydia is really a GUI front end for [apt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(Debian)), the homebrew equivalent on iOS and many other Linux systems, so a Cydia repo is really an apt repo.

You can use [CyDownload](https://github.com/borishonman/cydownload/releases) to view and download the packages(`.deb`s) on your computer. [image]

Some popular repos:

- BigBoss(http://apt.thebigboss.org/repofiles/cydia/)
- Packix(https://repo.packix.com/)
- Chariz(https://cydia.hbang.ws)
- Coolstar/Electra(https://electrarepo64.coolstar.org/) (for iOS >= 11)
- Saurik/Cydia(http://apt.saurik.com/) (for iOS <= 10)

Comment: I so love it when I learn things - great answer explaining the commonality between repos